# Integrate websockets in Osgi project with Atmosphere

Tags: java, maven, websocket, osgi, atmosphere

I tried to integrate websockets in my project that usees Osgi blueprint, cxf and jax-rs. As an inspiration I used the following project [1]. When I tried connecting to my server I received the following error:

```
org.atmosphere.runtime - 2.3.5 | Websocket protocol not supported
```

I don't know where the problem is. How can fix this problem?

Thanks.

[1] -https://github.com/apache/cxf/tree/master/distribution/src/main/release/samples/jax_rs/websocket_osgi